# Launching Spring cloud Task using Spring cloud deployer

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have a batch application, in Spring cloud task that is meant to be a short lived micro service. There are many such batch applications. Now, I can throw Spring Cloud deployer and its task launcher and with its help, we can start the Spring Cloud task.

What I found were all from command line. I want some java code that can use TaskLauncher, to execute the Task on Pivotal cloud Foundry.

Have anyone done this or can we even do this?

Answer (score 0):

We have an out-of-the-box [`tasklauncher-cloudfoundry`](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-cloudfoundry) that does exactly what you're looking for.

You can push it to PCF standalone (see [example](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-cloudfoundry/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-task-launcher-cloudfoundry/README.adoc#examples)) or define a [streaming-pipeline](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-launch-tasks-from-stream) in SCDF and let SCDF orchestrate that in the platform for you.

Comment: that's what I got from all the googling. By question is, how to achieve that using a java code, what we are doing using comandLine arguments